# Generate stand alone js artifacts using Vite as side effect of another build

Tags: node.js, typescript, vite, solid-js

I'm using Vite (vite@3.1.8)
to build Typescript artifacts for an SPA "site" using SolidJS (solid-js@1.6.0).

here's my vite.config.ts

```js
import { defineConfig, resolveBaseUrl } from 'vite'
import solidPlugin from 'vite-plugin-solid'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [solidPlugin()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
    outDir: '../htdocs',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        index: "./index.html",
        dev: "./dev.html",
        test: "./test.ts",
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Currently, it actually builds 2 html files (index.html and dev.html) and the artifacts needed to run those files.  Its great.  Couldn't be happier.

I would like to have the transpiler to also kick out test.js so that I can run it to do some sanity checking before deploying to production.

I'm hoping to do `vite build`, and then run `node ../htdocs/assets/test.js` (or something similar), and have it block the final deployment if any my sanity tests fail.

however, when I attempt to do this, I get an error when I run test.js, complaining about my use of import statements.

`Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`

setting my package type to module in package.json doesn't fix it.  changing the test file to test.mjs doesnt fix it.  I'm not really sure what to try next.

What I really wish it would do is do the whole "import" as part of transpiling, and make one self-contained test.js that just runs.  It seems like that is what it does when it builds index.html and dev.html, why wont it do that for my ts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find was to make a separate config file for building the tests.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import solidPlugin from 'vite-plugin-solid'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [solidPlugin()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
    outDir: '../htdocs',
    lib: {
      entry: "./test-runner.ts",
      name: "test-runner",
      fileName: "test-runner"
    },
    rollupOptions: {
    },
  },
});
```

and then, update my package.json to make my test script compile and run the output from that alternative vite config.

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "test": "vite build --config vite.config-tests.ts && node ../htdocs/test-runner.umd.js"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work. I just tried making a new repo with your `vite.config.ts`, one-line `index.html`, `dev.html`, and `test.ts` files, and `vite`, `vite-plugin-solid`, `solid-js` installed.  In the end I got a `../htdocs/assets/test.js` file.

You might also be interested in checking out [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/guide/) which makes testing like this easier to do, and won't accidentally end up in your deployed htdocs.

Comment: It does generate the test.js file.  that works the way I would expect it to.  But, that file doesnt "run" when I run it with node.   Because it doesnt have all of the TS imports.  it doesnt compile them in in the same way it does for the html includes.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I will investigate Vitest, because it looks interesting, but the choice of test frameworks is not mine to make, I have to yield that decision to the organization, which will take time.  My intention here is to have non-opinionated tests for the essential things without committing to a framework.   All I really want is a js output that will resolve and wrap up its own dependencies so I can run it.